# Missing Settings in "NVIDIA X Server Settings"

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, xorg, display

I've been searching for a way to change the colors of my laptop display.

In Windows I do it with `"Color Vibrance"` within `Intel Settings`. I got an i7-6700HQ and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 with 4.4.0-36-generic kernel. I tried everything like adding the Option `'Option "DigitalVibrance" "integer"'` from Nvidia Support WebSite, but that didn't change anything.

I tried different drivers (358.16; 361.45.18; 364.19; 367.44; 370.23) which did have effect on the performance but I still wasn't able to get these options.

What my Options look like:

[image: missing option]

And what I found others look like:

[image: normal options]

(Of course this is a computer with more than one screen but shouldn't it have it for my laptop screen too?). I didn't run earlier Ubuntu version until now because it's a new Laptop, but maybe I will check this option too.

### Edit

---

I just noticed that the `X Server Settings` dont recognize my build in display as a monitor. As you can see on the picture above it just says "Display Devices: None".

Maybe if i could change the xorg.conf right it would "recongnize" it?

What i found out so far by using `xrandr` is the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1 disconnected
HDMI-2 disconnected
```

so it's called `eDP-1` i guess, but I don't know how to modify the xorg.conf.